# Where to ask about programming ethics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a developer. I usually ask on Stack Overflow.

I have a situation, or "story", that involves: programming ethics, employer-employee relationship, company stocks, code property and taking decisions.

So, there are a few meta-questions:

1. On what Stack Exchange site can I post this situation?
2. Is it wrong to ask for opinions? because there might not be an accepted answer. Should I ask something very concrete at the end of my story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably ask at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). They do field software development workplace questions, a notable example being [Project Manager asks for complete 100% confidence everytime committing code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20098/16807). They have a [[software industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry)] tag, except it seems people tend to not use it, even for IT or software development industry questions.

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accepts a range of subjective programming questions, but this stuff appears to be off topic there:

> general workplace issues, office politics, and job hunting (check out The Workplace instead)

Comment: humm, so basically, in the correct place I won't get attention, and in the place that I would get attention, I'd be creating an off topic thread :/

Comment: What makes you think you won't get attention in The Workplace? The question I linked has 26k views and hit the hot network questions list. There's lots of IT questions there, they just seem to rarely use the software industry tag.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood you